# Libgdx RotateToAction does not directly rotate between 179 and -179

Tags: libgdx, rotation

It took me a bit of debugging to realize why I'm having trouble with my rotations and it seems that rather than just moving the 2 degrees between 179 and -179, it prefers to rotate all the way in the other direction, the full 358 degrees.

Is there any way to make it go the short way in this case?

Code I have so far:

```
public void rotateTo(float targetRotation)
    {
        RotateToAction rotateToAction = new RotateToAction();
        rotateToAction.setRotation(targetRotation);
        rotateToAction.setDuration(2f);
        if(Math.abs(this.getRotation()-targetRotation) > 180)
        {
        /*failed attempt to force rotation*/
            SequenceAction sequenceAction = new SequenceAction();
            RotateToAction rotateToAction2 = new RotateToAction();
            rotateToAction2.setRotation(180);
            rotateToAction2.setDuration(1f);
            sequenceAction.addAction(rotateToAction2);
             sequenceAction.addAction(rotateToAction);
            this.addAction(sequenceAction);
        }
        else
        {
            this.addAction(rotateToAction);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how the code works and this obviously won't work if any methods require an angle between -180 and 180 degrees, but rather than setting the target rotation to -179, could you instead set it to 181 degrees? To my (very limited) understanding that is the same angle as -179 degrees.

Comment: To be pedantic, -180 and 180 are the same position. A circle ranges from -180 to 179, or 0 to 359. The value 0 is counted also.

Comment: @FuzzyLogic Thanks for clarifying. My thinking was that the rotate action must increment through rotation values in a linear manner meaning that the difference between -180 and 180 would be 360, like it is on a number line, rather than 0, like it is on a radian circle, which is what is causing the object to rotate all the way around.

Comment: That does accomplish the task. However, with future rotations it's easy to end up with a "winding up" scenario where you then try to set it to 10, for example, and it spins multiple times coming back down to 10, after having wound up a bit. I'll be posting my solution  shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this library but a google search later I came up with following:

```
RotateToAction rotateToAction2 = new RotateToAction();
rotateToAction2.setReverse(true);
rotateToAction2.setRotation(180);
rotateToAction2.setDuration(1f);
```

I hope this works :)

Comment: setting reverse "*When true, the action's progress will go from 100% to 0%.*" - this causes it to jump to the end (rotated to -179), and then run backwards until it gets to the start (179), but still the long way.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own action using the RotateToAction source code as a template.

Essentially just added any of the code involving the number 360 ;)

```
public class DirectRotateAction extends TemporalAction
{
    private float start, end;

    protected void begin()
    {
        start = (this.getActor().getRotation()+360)%360;
        if (start - end > 180) end += 360;
        if (end - start > 180) start += 360;
    }

    protected void update(float percent)
    {
        this.getActor().setRotation((start+(end-start)*percent)%360);
    }

    public float getRotation() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setRotation(float rotation) {
        this.end = (rotation+360)%360;
    }
}
```